# How can I crop manipulator from a plot

Tags: manipulate, image-processing

I wanted to know how can I crop a `Manipulator` from a plot. the code for plot is

```
   a=  With[{z1 = .25, z2 = 1, x = 1}, 
   Manipulate[
  PopupWindow[
Graphics[
 DiscretePlot[Sin[a t], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}, ExtentSize -> Full, 
  ImageSize -> Scaled[x], AspectRatio -> z1/z2]], {a}], 
OpenerView[{"Vertical", Control[{{a, 1, "Manipulator"}, 1, 30}]}], 
ControlPlacement -> Bottom]]
```

I have tried using `Export` and `Import` functions and it is working fine

```
 ImageCrop[Import[Export["test.gif", a, "Graphics"]], 90]
```

But, I wanted to know some other way to do this as I think `Export` and `Import` takes a lot of time in execution.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how the manipulator relates to the gif in your question, but if you add PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {-1, 1}} to the Graphics[], it will prevent it from re-sizing the axes during the manipulation.

Comment: As much as I know `ImageCrop` works just with images, not with plots. If I understand you correctly, you want to have your plot again, but without the "manipulating background".
Then you could produce your plot for your chosen manipulator value again – so you get rid of the import and export.
If you want to crop this plot, then you should take a look [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsLayout.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could assign the `Graphics` part to a variable:

```
With[{z1 = .25, z2 = 1, x = 1},     
  Manipulate[   
     PopupWindow[ 
        graphOut = Graphics[DiscretePlot[Sin[a t], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}, 
                            ExtentSize -> Full, ImageSize -> Scaled[x], 
                            AspectRatio -> z1/z2]
                   ], 
       {a}
     ],  
     OpenerView[{"Vertical", Control[{{a, 1, "Manipulator"}, 1, 30}]}],   
     ControlPlacement -> Bottom
  ]
]
```

You can now use `graphOut` to produce the plot anywhere you like.

Answer (score 1):

In the top right corner of the `Manipulate` there is a button marked `+`. If you press this a popup menu appears. One of the options is "Paste SnapShot" which will paste a snapshot of the current setting in the form of a `DynamicModule`. Running this code will produce the image without the controllers and the panel.

[image: Mathematica graphics]